# some laravel route not changing to https

Tags: laravel, https, routes

There are some my route not going to HTTPS in my Javascript code

```
loadSettingTable("{{ route('setting.table.data.datatable') }}");
```

they become like this, so my datatable can't be load because mixed content.

```
loadSettingTable("http://*****.com/admin/data-setting-table/datatable");
```

but my css and JS file already become HTTPS.
I already give this on my AppServiceProvider and ENV

```
//AppServiceProvider.php on Boot
if(env('REDIRECT_HTTPS')) {
    $url->formatScheme('https');
    URL::forceScheme('https');
}
//.ENV
REDIRECT_HTTPS=true
```

But some of it work fine with this code, why my code with route name not giving https?

```
loadTableRealCommSumAgent("/agent/commissions-summary-member-ajax");
```

Comment: can't you add an role in your .htaccess to redirect any incoming to https instead ?

Comment: @SamuelAialaFerreira hm... on my other project I don't touch the htaccess but there is no problem like this...

Answer (score 0):

I found the error myself, but don't really know why this error happens on my production server not staging server. I remove $url->formatScheme('https'); because it giving some error on production but not always and it's fixed my problem.